# Client_secret and client_id values for posting to blogger

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth, blogger

I'm trying to build an app that posts sentences to Blogger. However I'm stuck at the oAuth part which requires a client ID and client secret. I don't know where to find these values.

The values are required in the following line:

```
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(httpTransport, jacksonFactory,
                        CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, scopes).setAccessType("online").setApprovalPrompt("auto").build();
```

How do I find the proper CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET values?

Answer (score 0):

All right, I found it. It involves going to https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/blogger.googleapis.com/ and then I can create tokens by clicking on the left hand menu.